# Override angularJS trim in div

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-model, trim

I'm currently working on a ticket where I need to add a @Tag at the start of a div, using ng-model property. I'm required to add a space after the @Tag, so that users can start typing right away.

[Tag trimmed example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bux7W.png)

However, I found that ng-model trims the whitespace as long as I don't add some other character after, and that ng-trim doesn't work on div. The code is too complex to change the div into an input, so I was wondering if there was another way I can override this whitespace trim?

`$scope.divContent = "This div needs to have an empty space at its end   " + " ";`

Here's a [JsFiddle illustrating the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/b5n1hutk/9/).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like if you do not use `ng-trim` there is no white space trimming. Also using the css property `white-space: pre;` helps preserve the white spaces!

Please check the below example!!

```js
function LoginController($scope) {
  $scope.divContent = "This div needs to have an empty space at its end   " + " ";
  $scope.user = {
    firstName: "Foo",
    lastName: "Bar"
  };
  $scope.logins = [];
  $scope.login = function() {
    $scope.logins.push($scope.user.firstName + " was logged in.");
  };
}
```

```css
.background {
  background-color: #23aa54;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 200px;
}

div {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.special{
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="background" ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">
  <div ng-bind="divContent" ng-trim="false"></div>
  <!-- this code is having the white space trimmed -->
  <div ng-bind="divContent" class="special"></div>
  <!-- this code is not having the white space trimmed -->
</div>
```